# How to send PushNotification to iOS device with C# asp.net .netcore in webapi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, apple-push-notifications, webapi

I'm trying to send a PushNotification Message to a list of `iOS device`.
My constraints are :

- code is inside a webapi controller
- web server is a Windows 2012 R2
- using asp.net / .net core (actually 3.1)

First, I decided to use p8 file instead of p12 (it seems Apple prefere it).

I crawled many SO questions, trying about 5-6 solutions, but i still get same results :

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   Win32Exception: Le message reçu était inattendu ou formaté de façon
>   incorrecte. Unknown location
>
> AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
>   System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken
>   message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo
>   exception)
>
> HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see
>   inner exception.
>   System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream
>   stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)

From french "Win32Exception: Le message reçu était inattendu ou formaté de façon incorrecte", in English would be "Win32Exception: The message received was unexpected or badly formatted"

To format the JWT, i've used the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58237524/6368101) from Bourne Koloh.

I've also tried **PushSharp** and **CoreSharp** with same error.

When I extract data from the p8 file, i have all the file without first and last line, and without linebreak.

When i use the **Push Notifications Tester** application, it works, the message is delivered to the device.

By the way, i've added the both p12 certificate (dev and prod) to the Windows 2012 R2 server 
I probably miss something important but still don't know what.

Since the message say it's a problem of authentication, I guess it's around the JWT and the the p8 file.

How I extract the p8 file data :

```
var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("AuthKey.p8");
var list = data.Split('\n').ToList();
var prk = list.Where((s, i) => i != 0 && i != list.Count - 1).Aggregate((agg, s) => agg + s);

var key = new ECDsaCng(CngKey.Import(Convert.FromBase64String(prk), CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob));
```

Il also tried this way (with BouncyCastle ):

```
using (var reader = System.IO.File.OpenText("AuthKey.p8"))
{
    var ecPrivateKeyParameters = (ECPrivateKeyParameters)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();
    var x = ecPrivateKeyParameters.Parameters.G.AffineXCoord.GetEncoded();
    var y = ecPrivateKeyParameters.Parameters.G.AffineYCoord.GetEncoded();
    var d = ecPrivateKeyParameters.D.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
    var key = ECDsaCng(EccKey.New(x, y, d));
}
```

And now how I build the JWT :

try #1 : using Jose package.

```
private string GetProviderToken(ECDsaCng key)
{
    var epochNow = (int)DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970,1,1)).TotalSeconds;
    var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "iss", "THETEAMID" },
        { "iat", epochNow }
    };

    var extraHeaders = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "kid", "THEKEYID"}
    };

    return JWT.Encode(payload, key, JwsAlgorithm.ES256, extraHeaders);
}
var token = GetProviderToken(key);
```

try #2 :

```
private string CreateToken(ECDsa key, string keyID, string teamID)
{
    var securityKey = new ECDsaSecurityKey(key) { KeyId = keyID };
    var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, "ES256");

    var descriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        IssuedAt = DateTime.Now,
        Issuer = teamID,
        SigningCredentials = credentials
    };
    descriptor.Expires = null;
    descriptor.NotBefore = null;
    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var encodedToken = handler.CreateEncodedJwt(descriptor);
    return encodedToken;
}
var token = CreateToken(key, "THEKEYID", "THETEAMID");
```

try #3

```
private string SignES256(string privateKey, string header, string payload)
{
    CngKey key = CngKey.Import(Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey), CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob);
    using (ECDsaCng dsa = new ECDsaCng(key))
    {
        dsa.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
        var unsignedJwtData =              Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header)) + "." + Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));
        var signature = dsa.SignData(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(unsignedJwtData));
        return unsignedJwtData + "." + Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(signature);
    }
}
var token = SignES256(prk, "{\"alg\":\"ES256\" ,\"kid\":\"THEKEYID\"}", "{ \"iss\": \"THETEAMID\",\"iat\":" + (int)DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds + "\" }");
```

If I'm not using a library (CorePush, etc) for sending the http message, i do this way :

```
var url = string.Format("https://api.sandbox.push.apple.com/3/device/{0}", deviceToken);
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("apns-push-type", "alert"); // or background
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("apns-id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D"));
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("apns-expiration", Convert.ToString(0));
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("apns-priority", Convert.ToString(10));
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("apns-topic", "com.company.project");
request.Content = new StringContent("{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Hello\"},\"yourCustomKey\":\"1\"}");
// also tried without yourcustomkey
request.Version = new Version(2, 0); // tried directly with System.Net.HttpVersion.Version20;
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls; // Tried with only Tls12
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => true;
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.SendAsync(request).ContinueWith(responseTask =>
    {
        return responseTask.Result; // line of error
    });
    if (resp != null)
    {
        string apnsResponseString = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        handler.Dispose();
        //ALL GOOD ....
        return Ok(apnsResponseString);
    }

    handler.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: What if to try out Google’s Firebase? It is more easy and free.

Comment: I've read some pages about Firebase, and I didn't get how it works, it sounds more complicated to me, even if it could work for both Apple and Android devices.

Comment: Firebase works for Android and iOS too. They just need to have Firebase message token that you could push them.

Comment: @NicolasVieira did you ever get this working?  I have received the same errors as you following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@sunnysun_5694/send-push-notification-from-net-service-to-ios-devices-using-pushsharp-7a7bf9f7fb36

I am about to just use CorePush but not seeing good documentation, any info would be helpful!

Comment: @Jh2170 I used the workaround suggested by Artavazd : Google Firebase. At least the aim is reached : notification are sent and received.